# jQuery - Selector based on Attribute

Tags: jquery, variables

I have this selector attempt:

```
<textarea tinymce="basicoptions"></textarea>
<textarea tinymce="advancedoptions"></textarea>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('textarea[tinymce]').each(function(){ 
   var tinymceopts = $(this).attr('tinymce');
   $(this).tinymce(tinymceopts); 

});
</script>
```

Simply, I'm using my custom attribute, called `tinymce` to hold a string, which is the name of a variable I store in a javascript file.
(example inside javascript file:  `var basicoptions = { ....stuff.... }`
And inside that variable holds the custom options for the tinymce editor.

The code above does not work.  But if I replace the `$(this).tinymce(tinymceopts);` with one of the actual variables:  `$(this).tinymce(basicoptions);`  it works fine.

I actually have 4 variables to work with, but I've show only 2 above.

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok after re-reading your question, it sounds like you just need to access a variable with the name similar to the attribute. Assuming it's a global variable, do it like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('textarea[tinymce]').each(function(){ 
   var tinymceopts = $(this).attr('tinymce');
   $(this).tinymce(window[tinymceopts]); 
});
```

Instead of passing the string 'basicoptions' to the `tinymce` method, you're now referencing a variable `window.basicoptions` which should map to your `var basicoptions` variable, assuming the scope was indeed at the global level. If it wasn't, just replace `window` with the applicable namespace.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't seem to be an issue regarding the jQuery attribute selector, or even jQuery at all.

From my understanding you've created four variables with different sets of options for the editor - instead of this, why not create one object with multiple properties?

```
var config = {
    basic: {...},
    advanced: {...}
};
```

This way you can access the correspondent configurations doing something like:

```
$('textarea[tinymce]').each(function() {
   var tinymceopts = $(this).attr('tinymce');
   $(this).tinymce(config[tinymceopts]);
});
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible to place the options in a dataset attribute ([docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.dataset)) right in the markup? Then you could use the jQuery `data()` ([docs](http://api.jquery.com/data/)) method to retrieve the options directly, without having to use a secondary variable.

You can put a JSON string in the attribute and jQuery will automagically parse it into a usable object.

```
<textarea class="tinymce" data-tinymceoptions='{"option":"option_value"}'></textarea>

$('textarea.tinymce').each(function(){
    var options = $(this).data('tinymceoptions');
    // pass the options on to the tiny MCE library
});
```

Try it on jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gF5Uq/

**Documentation**

- `jQuery.data` - http://api.jquery.com/data/
- HTML5 element datasets on MDN - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.dataset